# mutate column based on external list in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can i mutate

```
my_df <-data.frame(A=(1:4),
                     B= c('a','b','c','d'))
list<-c('c','d','a')
```

I want to create a new column `list_column` that should state 0 and 1 values based on if `column c` value present in list. I am trying to do it with `mutate` but nothing works.
My output should be

```
A B list_column
1 a           1
2 b           0
3 c           1
4 d           1
```

Comment: You can use `mutate(my_df, list_column = B %in% unlist(list) + 0)` The `%in%` operator checks for membership. It normally returns TRUE/FALSE but you can use +0 to change that to 1/0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R method:

```r
within(my_df, list_column  <- as.integer(B %in% list))
#   A B list_column
# 1 1 a           1
# 2 2 b           0
# 3 3 c           1
# 4 4 d           1
```